Pattern of vortex generated due to an open manhole on street in rainy season
Recently, a person lost their life by falling into an open manhole on the street as it was not visible in the monsoon season of Mumbai. link to twitter
Can a common person (or even a fluid dynamist, for that matter) have some idea of the presence of an open manhole if the streets are flooded by water? Say by looking for a vortex. The actual answer might depend on the height of the water surface on the street, the diameter of the manhole and the typical average velocity of the water flow.

For a vortex one needs to have a flow - if the manhole is simply flooded, you can't see (unless the water is somewhat transparent.)

Don't over-think this.
Carry a stick and probe the flooded street ahead of you as you walk.  This should find places which are deeper than the surrounding areas and could be potential potholes or open manholes.  You don't have to know for sure it's an open manhole, just know it could be, to avoid it.
This would also help spot places where submerged obstacles exist and can be avoided.

Do over-think this. If there is a current, you might lose your footing if you get near the manhole. Currents exert surprisingly high forces on you. A pole is a good thought. But seeing it from a distance is better.

@mmesser314 I'd suggest that if the current was that strong you'd probably see it's effects, even if the water motion itself is not visible, due to floating objects (leaves, rubbish, etc) going with the flow.  Not much help if you're blind, of course, and if anyone has a solution for those unfortunate enough to be blind, let people know.
